# Testing API with PostAsync and Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, xunit

I wrote a REST API in C# that uses a business logic and some data access to work with a database.
Now I want to test the API using PostAsync, GetAsync and DeleteAsync Methods in the xUnit Framework.

But I do not want to use my actual database, but a testdatbase.
The problem is that I need to check the response body and the status code and therefore need to use the data access and a test database.
I simply don't know where to start. I believe I have to implement some kind of interface that uses a testdatabase and some response handler for my unit tests.
I can't find any tutorials that involve both, a test datbase for unit tests and a real database for the program.

Any idea how I can handle this issue?
Hit me up, if I should provide some code.

EDIT: here is some code that might explain the issue

I want my tests to look something like this and to return the list of items

```
 [Fact]
        public async Task GetAllItemsTest()
        {
            HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();

            HttpResponseMessage message = await Client.GetAsync("https://localhost:xxxxx/api/AllItems") as List<Item>;

Assert.True(Check if list contains the expexted number of elements)            
Assert.Equal("OK",message.StatusCode.ToString());

        }
    }
```

Also I need to check the database when testing my POST methods.
Just so I can see that an entry was added.
Maybe something like this:

```
 [Fact]
        public async Task AddNewItemTest()
        {
            HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();

            HttpContent content = new HttpContent {itemName = "NewItem"};

            HttpResponseMessage message = await       Client.PostAsync("https://localhost:xxxxx/api/NewItem", content);

Assert.True(Check if entry to database was made)            
Assert.Equal("OK",message.StatusCode.ToString());

        }
    }
```

Data access consist of a controller that implements a constructor for my Database context. Basically all data access methods look like GetItems().
I use EF Core.

```
 public class ItemsController : ControllerBase
    {

        //Constructor for DB usage 
        private DataContext _context;

        public ItemsController(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        // Get all Items
        public List<Items> GetItems()
        {

            return _context.Items.ToList();
        }

    // Add new Item
        public void AddItem(Item item)
        {
                _context.Items.Add(item);
                _context.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Comment: xUnit doesn't have such methods. Databases don't use HTTP verbs either.  Do you mean `HttpClient.PostAsync`? If you want to unit test the data access code, you should call those data access methods directly, not go through the HTTP API.

Comment: Post code that demonstrates the problem and explain what is going on, which data access libraries you use. Plain ADO.NET? EF? Dapper? Something else? If you want to mock the database, different techniques can be used with different libraries, eg an in-memory provider for EF Core. Using a test database isn't a bad idea either. All you have to do is change the connection string used by your data access methods

Comment: I already set up a test database. Can I switch the connection strings automatically when starting my tests? Also, I added some code to my post.

Comment: That code has nothing to do with data access. Where's the data access code? Have you written any data access tests?

Comment: I added some of the data access code and the constructor of the data access class.

Comment: That's not a data access class. That's a Web API controller. The data access class is `DataContext`. In any case, you can test each of them individually. You can configure `DataContext` to target a test database or an Dictionary<> by using the constructor that accepts `DbContextOptions`. You can test the controller by creating a DbContext first, then passing it to the controller's constructor

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean. I'll try to target a test database and see if it works.